# MYSQL/JDBC Forming a JDBC connection URL to connect to a database having a question mark(?) in its name?

Tags: java, mysql, url, jdbc, database-connection

I have a database with a name `order?id`(don't ask me why). The connection url I formed is

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/order?id
```

which seems to be invalid as it throws an error

```
Unknown database "order"
```

It is because `?` is treated as a separator(or some character having special significance, I really don't know).

So after doing some research, I found that the URL can be `percent encoded`, replacing `?` in database name with `%3F` like

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/order%3Fid
```

Which still fails as the DB is trying to look for the database`order%3Fid` and not `order?id`. So it cannot find the database and throws an error.

Also tried replacing `?` with `??` as suggested by some websites. Still doesn't work. How do we specify such db names?

*Edit*

Tried adding single quote in the database name as

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/'order?id'
```

Still no luck.

Comment: Have you tried placing single quote around the db name? `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/'order?id'
`

Comment: You could also try replacing the `?` by `&quest;`. Searching for your problem doesn't return much, people have the same problem with passwords which often include special chars, but using url encoding works just fine there

Comment: @Shafiul tried but no luck.

Comment: @Aaron tried &quest. not working

Comment: Are you sure the `?` in the database name is actually a `?` ? I just remembered sometimes unprintable chars are displayed as `?`. Might be worth scrutinizing the table name as it's stored in system tables. At least [the doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-jdbc-url-format.html) says URL encoding should work anywhere in the connection string

Comment: @Aaron absolutely. Because I myself created the database.

Comment: Try `order_id`. I try to create DB in MSSQL using `order?id` and its logical name is stored as `order_id`

Comment: Make sure you are using the latest version of MySQL Connector/J. If URL encoding doesn't work, then it probably cannot be done. If you really cannot rename your database, try connecting to `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/` and use `connection.setCatalog("order?id")` afterwards.